# Golang Web Crawler solution, 2 data races, exit status 66

Tags: go, synchronization, web-crawler, mutex

I have been following this [solution](https://github.com/fgrehm/go-tour/blob/master/73-web-crawler-golang-team-solution.go). There is no race condition detected when i run race detecter. But when i run race detecter with my code it gives the following error:

> ================== WARNING: DATA RACE Read at 0x00c42006c1e0 by goroutine 6:   main.Crawl.func1()
>         /task2.go:50 +0x53
>
> Previous write at 0x00c42006c1e0 by main goroutine:   main.Crawl()
>         /task2.go:48 +0x692   main.main()
>         /task2.go:66 +0x8c
>
> Goroutine 6 (running) created at:   main.Crawl()
>         /task2.go:49 +0x61e   main.main()
>         /task2.go:66 +0x8c
>   ================== . . .
>   ================== WARNING: DATA RACE Read at 0x00c420094070 by goroutine 8:   main.Crawl.func1()
>         /task2.go:50 +0x53
>
> Previous write at 0x00c420094070 by goroutine 6:   main.Crawl()
>         /task2.go:48 +0x692   main.Crawl.func1()
>         /task2.go:51 +0x240
>
> Goroutine 8 (running) created at:   main.Crawl()
>         /task2.go:49 +0x61e   main.Crawl.func1()
>         /task2.go:51 +0x240
>
> Goroutine 6 (running) created at:   main.Crawl()
>         /task2.go:49 +0x61e   main.main()
>
> ## /task2.go:66 +0x8c
>
> Found 2 data race(s) exit status 66

Following is my code, can anyone please tell me where i'm going wrong. I have been trying to figure it out for so long but could not identify.

```
        var visited = struct {
        urls map[string]bool
        sync.Mutex
    }{urls: make(map[string]bool)}

    func Crawl(url string, depth int, fetcher Fetcher) {

        if depth <= 0 {
            return
        }

        visited.Lock()
        if visited.urls[url] && visited.urls[url] == true {
            fmt.Println("already fetched: ", url)

            visited.Unlock()
            return
        }
        visited.urls[url] = true
        visited.Unlock()

        body, urls, err := fetcher.Fetch(url)

        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            return
        }
        done := make(chan bool)

        for _, nestedUrl := range urls {
            go func(url string, d int) {
                fmt.Printf("-> Crawling child %v of %v with depth %v \n", nestedUrl, url, depth)
                Crawl(url, d, fetcher)
                done <- true

            }(nestedUrl, depth-1)
        }
        for i := range urls {
            fmt.Printf("<- [%v] %v/%v Waiting for child %v.\n", url, i, len(urls))
            <-done
        }
        fmt.Printf("<- Done with %v\n", url)
    }

    func main() {
        Crawl("http://golang.org/", 4, fetcher)

        fmt.Println("Fetching stats\n--------------")

        for url, err := range visited.urls {
            if err != true {
                fmt.Printf("%v failed: %v\n", url, err)
            } else {
                fmt.Printf("%v was fetched\n", url)
            }
        }
  }
```

Comment: Could you show the whole file? May be on play.google.com or github? Now it's not obvious where're that lines with race panic.

Comment: It is *probably* the use of `nestedUrl` in the child goroutine `Printf` call.

Comment: if you don't share the whole file we cannot know what line is failing

Comment: Do give line nos in future or all code on playground as it makes it much easier.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response here is the code file https://github.com/aneelaSaleem/Go/blob/master/task2.go

Comment: Yes @MiloChristiansen You were right. I changed the nestedUrl in the child goroutine Printf call to url. And it looks fine now. Race detector didn't detected any race condition now

Answer (score 0):

You’re calling Crawl, which fires off a go routine to recurse, then you’re accessing the protected map visited without a mutex in main which is executed before some crawls finish. A few points on style:

- Prefer a synchronous api
- Put the visited struct in charge of locking (no public lock)
- Use a wait group or channels in main to wait for completion

So start synchronous, then figure out how best to change to async. You can then make it a sync just by putting go in front of your synchronous crawl function. Looking at the original tour, it doesn't much resemble this solution, so I'm not sure this is a great model to follow. The caller should not have to lock or worry about races, so you need to redesign. I'd start again from the [original tour exercise](https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/10).

For the lock, I'd use

```
type T struct {
data map[string]bool
mu sync.Mutex // not just sync.Mutex
}
```

and the T decides when locking is required and has functions to adjust the state of data or search it. This makes it simpler to think about using the Lock and less likely you make a mistake.

Comment: Thanks for the response Kenny.

"Prefer a synchronous api"
What does that mean? I mean i'm already trying to do it synchronously

 "Put the visited struct in charge of locking (no public lock)"
Can you please show me an example?

"Use a wait group or channels in main to wait for completion"
Already using a channel to wait for completion of all go routines

Comment: Even if you intend to use the go keyword, start by writing a non async version. This is a special case, but normally the caller decides whether to call async or not. You can convert sync to async with the go keyword, but never async to sync. Then the callee decides when to lock their data, if you need to lock, don't use the map outside the function or expose the Lock functions.